graph api date filter not working and returns dates outside of filter
I'm trying to return a list of news pages after a specific date with the graph api, but the date filter on the following query doesn't seem to work when using graph explorer. Any thoughts?
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/000000000-d28a-4cb8-0000-366b2884a2f9,99bf8ea8-00e8-45dc-0000-d8ab022dbf06/pages/microsoft.graph.sitePage?$filter=createdDateTime+gt+2024-04-22T00:00:00Z

